# How to `GROUP BY` properly for MySQL `FROM_UNIXTIME` in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

This code I've tried so far:

```
$this->db->group_by('FROM_UNIXTIME(mec.dt_start,"%Y-%D-%M"');
```

But got error like this:

```
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(mec.dt_start, `"%Y-%D-%M")`
```

Anyone got ideas how to solve this?

*Extra information:*

```
function get_events_data($limit='',$offset='',$type='calendar')
{
    $search_input = $this->session->userdata('search_input');
    $this->db->set_dbprefix('');

    db_select('mu.fullname');
    db_select('mu.username');
    db_select('me.event_id');
    db_select('me.user_id');
    db_select('me.user_type');
    db_select('me.event_name');
    db_select('me.url_id');
    db_select('me.event_details');
    db_select('me.is_payment_required');
    db_select('mec.remarks');
    db_select('mec.fee');
    db_select('mec.max_pax');
    db_select('mec.bal_pax');
    db_select('mec.deleted_status');
    db_select('mec.calendar_id');
    db_select('mec.event_state_id');
    db_select('mec.venue_location');
    db_select('mec.dt_start,mec.dt_end');
    db_select('mec.approval_status,mec.deleted_status');
    db_where('mec.dt_start >= ',time());
    db_where('mec.dt_start <=',strtotime(MAX_TIME_EVENT_CALENDAR_DISPLAY));
    db_join('m_event_calendar mec','mec.event_id=me.event_id','left');
    db_join('m_users mu','mu.user_id=me.user_id','left');
    if($type=='event_list' || $type == 'url_id'):
        db_group('FROM_UNIXTIME(mec.dt_start,"%Y-%D-%M")');
    endif;
    db_order('FROM_UNIXTIME(mec.dt_start)','asc');
    if($this->curuser):
        db_where('(me.user_id = '.$this->curuser['user_id'].' or me.approval_status = '.EVENT_APRROVAL_STATUS_APPROVED.')');
    else:
        db_where('me.approval_status',EVENT_APRROVAL_STATUS_APPROVED);
    endif;
    db_where('mec.deleted_status',EVENT_DELETED_STATUS_NO);
    if(!empty($search_input)):
        $this->db->like('me.event_name', $search_input,'match');
        $this->db->or_like('me.venue_location', $search_input,'match');
    endif;
    if($limit == '' || $offset == ''):
        $sql = db_get('m_event_list me');
    else:
        $sql = db_get('m_event_list me', $limit,  uri_segment($offset));
    endif;      

    $array = $sql->result_array();

    $this->db->set_dbprefix('m_');
    if($array):
        return $array;
    endif;
}
```

Notes (My custom db helper):

```
db_select --> stand for $this->db->select
db_group --> stand for $this->db->group_by
db_get --> stand for $this->db->get
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How to escape the character ` for --> `"%Y-%D-%M"  ...that makes my sql statement got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got my answer by add this code

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
```

before start my query.

```
function get_events_data($limit='',$offset='',$type='calendar',$option=1)
{
    $search_input = $this->session->userdata('search_input');
    $this->db->set_dbprefix('');
    $this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
    db_select('mu.fullname',false);
    db_select('mu.username');
    db_select('me.event_id');
    db_select('me.user_id');
    db_select('me.user_type');
    db_select('me.event_name');
    db_select('me.url_id');
    db_select('me.event_details');
    db_select('me.is_payment_required');
    db_select('mec.remarks');
    db_select('mec.fee');
    db_select('mec.max_pax');
    db_select('mec.bal_pax');
    db_select('mec.deleted_status');
    db_select('mec.calendar_id');
    db_select('mec.event_state_id');
    db_select('mec.venue_location');
    db_select('mec.dt_start,mec.dt_end');
    db_select('mec.approval_status,mec.deleted_status');
    db_where('mec.dt_start >= ',time());
    db_where('mec.dt_start <=',strtotime(MAX_TIME_EVENT_CALENDAR_DISPLAY));
    db_join('m_event_calendar mec','mec.event_id=me.event_id','left');
    db_join('m_users mu','mu.user_id=me.user_id','left');
    if($type=='event_list' || $type == 'url_id'):
        $this->db->group_by('FROM_UNIXTIME(mec.dt_start, "%Y-%M-%d")');
    endif;
    db_order('FROM_UNIXTIME(mec.dt_start)','asc');
    if($this->curuser):
        db_where('(me.user_id = '.$this->curuser['user_id'].' or me.approval_status = '.EVENT_APRROVAL_STATUS_APPROVED.')');
    else:
        db_where('me.approval_status',EVENT_APRROVAL_STATUS_APPROVED);
    endif;
    db_where('mec.deleted_status',EVENT_DELETED_STATUS_NO);
    if(!empty($search_input)):
        $this->db->like('me.event_name', $search_input,'match');
        $this->db->or_like('me.venue_location', $search_input,'match');
    endif;
    if($limit == '' || $offset == ''):
        $sql = db_get('m_event_list me');
    else:
        $sql = db_get('m_event_list me', $limit,  uri_segment($offset));
    endif;      
    if($option==1):
        $array = $sql->result_array();
    else:
        $array = $sql;
    endif;

    $this->db->set_dbprefix('m_');
    if($array):
        return $array;
    endif;
}
```

Thanks for all for helping me. Hope it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check with following :

```
$this->db->group_by('FROM_UNIXTIME(mec.dt_start,"%Y-%D-%M")',FALSE);
```

Comment: Not work. Since codeigniter does not provide the same argument as in select

Comment: give me your full query to check it